# Split datatable to multiple tables based on condition

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a Datatable like this

Id        Name     ParentId

---

```
1         AA        0
2         BB        1
3         CC2       1
4         DD        1           
5         EE        0
6         FF        5
7         GG        5 
8         HH        0     
9         II        8
```

I want to split the datatable Like this

Id        Name     ParentId

---

```
2         BB        1
3         CC2       1
4         DD        1        



Id        Name     ParentId
```

---

```
6         FF        5
7         GG        5
```

Id        Name     ParentId

---

```
9         II        8
```

the spliting is based on the rows BETWEEN the parentId ='0'

Help me pls..
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use the enumerable with the group by.  You will get a table of the 0 items but just throw it away/skip it.  The Copy will create the individual data tables within the list that will hold the separate tables you need.

```
List<DataTable> subTables = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("ParentId")).Select(g => g.CopyToDataTable()).ToList();
```